# convert List<E> to Map<String, List<String>> using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for some help in converting a List of objects to a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

```
class Person {   
    private String name;    
    private int age;
}
```

I have a `List<Person>` and I want to collect `Map<int, List<String>>` with key being age and value being list of names of Persons with same age.

I tried in these lines but did not work

```
persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAge()), );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this overload of [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) which accepts a downstream collector:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge,
                Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of this is to enable fast lookup, have you thought about using an indexed collection like Data Store:

https://github.com/jparams/data-store

You can do something like :

```
Store<Person> store = new MemoryStore<Person>();
store.index("name", Person::getName);
store.addAll(listOfPeople); // populate your store with data
Person personFound = person.get("name", "bob");
```

You can multiple indexes on the same data. You can even create case insensitive indexes etc.